# doctrine join multiple tables

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

Just started using doctrine. question. I have a lookup table that does 2 joins. How can I do this in Doctrine?

My SQL statement looks like this in mysql

```
select * from Business b 
inner join BusinessCategoryLookup on b.BusinessID= BusinessCategoryLookup .BusinessID inner join BusinessCategory bb on b.BusinessCategoryID= BusinessCategoryLookup .BusinessCategoryID;
```

Essentially I need to return all the business and their associated categories they belong too. The Lookup  table is just categoryID, business ID  as the columns.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your Business entity has `businessCategoryLookup` and `businessCategory` fields:

```
SELECT b, bcl, bc FROM YourBundleName:Business
JOIN b.businessCategoryLookup bcl
JOIN b.businessCategory bc
```

A lot clearer than SQL, eh ? :)

Comment: they do not.. I should add them?

Comment: Did you make entities at all? If not, please read some documentation before posting questions. If yes, how did you map them?